# How do I create a member that has an out parameter in F#

Tags: f#, clr

I know that in f# I can treat `out` parameters as members of a result tuple when I'm using them from F#, e.g.

```
(success, i) = System.Int32.TryParse(myStr)
```

What I'd like to know is how I define a member to have signature that appears to C# as having an `out` parameter.

Is it possible to do this? And can I just return a tuple and have the opposite process occur when I call the method from C#, e.g.

```
type Example() =
  member x.TryParse(s: string, success: bool byref)
    = (false, Unchecked.defaultof<Example>)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you can't return the result as a tuple -- you need to assign the value to the byref value before returning the result from the function. Also note the `[<Out>]` attribute -- if you leave that out, the parameter acts like a C# `ref` parameter.

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type Foo () =
    static member TryParse (str : string, [<Out>] success : byref<bool>) : Foo =
        // Manually assign the 'success' value before returning
        success <- false

        // Return some result value
        // TODO
        raise <| System.NotImplementedException "Foo.TryParse"
```

If you want your method to have a canonical C# `Try` signature (e.g., `Int32.TryParse`), you should return a `bool` from your method and pass the possibly-parsed `Foo` back through the `byref<'T>`, like so:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type Foo () =
    static member TryParse (str : string, [<Out>] result : byref<Foo>) : bool =
        // Try to parse the Foo from the string
        // If successful, assign the parsed Foo to 'result'
        // TODO

        // Return a bool indicating whether parsing was successful.
        // TODO
        raise <| System.NotImplementedException "Foo.TryParse"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type Test() = 
    member this.TryParse(text : string, [<Out>] success : byref<bool>) : bool = 
       success <- false
       false
let ok, res = Test().TryParse("123")
```